# Set Timeline XML with other Timeline XML

Tags: development, sharepoint-server, visual-web-part

I have two timeline webparts: Source and Destination.
I have to 'export' or duplicate the Source Timeline View in the destination Time Line.

```
    XmlDocument timelineXML = new XmlDocument();
    timelineXML.LoadXml(sourceTasklist.RootFolder.Properties["Timeline_Timeline"].ToString());

    var root = destinationTasklist.RootFolder;
                            root.SetProperty("TimelineDefaultView", "View");                               
                            root.SetProperty("TimelineAllViews", "Timeline");
                            root.SetProperty("Timeline_Timeline", timelineXML.OuterXml);

                            destinationTasklist.RootFolder.Update();
```

But I don't see any changes in my destination Timeline. Does Anyone have ideas?